# Overfitting? Is it ok, if I've met my desired threshold?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, f1score

I've trained a lightgbm classification model, selected features, and tuned the hyperparameters all to obtain a model that appears to work well.

When I've come to evaluate it on an out of bag selection of data, it appears to be slightly overfit to the training data.

*CV mean F1 score.* = `.80`

*OOB F1 score* = `.77`

For me this appears to be an acceptable tolerance. For my chosen requirements an out of bag score of .77 is perfectly acceptable.

How do we tell if this score is overfit? Is it? Or is overfit just a concept left for us to determine our self?

Is there a method to calculate an acceptable tolerance between a cross validated and out of bag evaluation metric -  or is it all empirical?

Comment: Overfitting is concept which is left for us to determine but anything greater than 5% diff in training and test set should lead to more drilldown. I am not aware of any formulae like that which means its all empirical

Comment: @Ashwiniku918 the performance difference on the training & test set in itself says *nothing* about overfitting; the latter enters the picture when the test error starts increasing while the training error continues to decrease.

Comment: @desertnaut I agree that in general one needs a broader picture in order to make a reliable diagnosis, but I don't completely agree with your first statement: I think that there can be cases which show clear overfitting only from perf on training and test set, but it has to be really obvious (very high perf on training, very low perf on test set). Of course the case in this question is not an obvious one.

Comment: @Erwan the telltale signature of overfitting is [this plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Overfitting_svg.svg) from Wikipedia (error vs training iterations); until mid-graph, there is not any overfitting whatsoever, despite the gap between training & test error. The latter is a completely different notion altogether, termed the [generalization gap](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/07/predicting-generalization-gap-in-deep.html) (no coincidence you will not find a single occurrence of the term "overfitting" in the article). And a performance gap may very well be the result of *under*fitting..

Comment: @desertnaut Thank you for your answer, but I disagree: what you're describing is the specific case of detecting overfitting where the training algorithm progresses incrementally by training cycles. For example there's no incremental training in Naive Bayes, but a NB model can be overfit. It could be detected similarly by looking at the evolution of performance across different number of training instances, for instance. Imho in the graph you link there are actually multiple models, one for every point x: the ones before the vertical line are not overfit,whereas the ones after the line are.

Comment: So I think that overfitting is a property which applies to a single model, but I agree that it's easier to detect by comparison to other models like in your example. I'm under the impression that maybe you're talking specifically about deep learning, but overfitting also applies to traditional models. Afaik underfitting would have a different effect: both the training and test set performance would be low.

Comment: @Erwan you do have a point, although I am not talking only about DL (traditional models, like RFs & boosted trees, work similarly with iterations). My point is - you can (and should) not lightheartedly assign overfitting whenever there is a gap between your training & test performance (which, in practice, will be *always* present). To be honest, I have not given much thought to the concept of overfitting in models like NB.